# Calculate percentage change in two list

Tags: python, list

I have a two list. `list1[4,3,2,5,6,0,0,1]` and `list2[1,2,5,0,7,0,1,8]`.I have to check the percentage change w.r.t `list1`. If percent growth is positive tag it as `1`. 
My code is:

```
percent_growth = []

target = []

for i in range(0,len(list1)):

    if list1[i] == 0:

      percent_growth.append(-9999)
      target.append(0)

      continue

      growth = (list2[i]-list1[i])/list1[i]
      percent_growth.append(growth*100)
      if growth > 0:
          target.append(1)
      else:
          target.append(0)
```

But my output is:

```
percent_growth:[-9999,-9999]
```

Comment: please format the python code

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: Your indentation is incorrect. The stuff after `continue` should _not_ be indented under the previous `if` block. When I fix the indentation, I get these results: `[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]` and `[-75.0, -33.33333333333333, 150.0, -100.0, 16.666666666666664, -9999, -9999, 700.0]`

Comment: percent_growth=[-75, -33.33, 150, -100, -9999,-9999, 700]. I have to calculate percentage change .w.r.t list1 . suppose when value of list1 elemnt is zero i will put a large negative number there

Answer (score -1):

The issue with your code is when iterating you are checking for 0 in list1 you
are running a continue defaulting value to -9999 and 0.
the following code post continue should be outside of if condition.

```
growth = (list2[i]-list1[i])/list1[i]
percent_growth.append(growth*100)
if growth > 0:
    target.append(1)
else:
    target.append(0)
```

You can use list comprehension.
zip the two lists

```
a=[4,3,2,5,6,0,0,1] 
b=[1,2,5,0,7,0,1,8]
```

> zip(a,b) create a tuple of two lists. Then use list comprehension to achieve.

```
per_growth = [-9999 if x == 0 else (((y - x) * 100) / x) for x, y in zip(a, b) ]
target = [ 1 if t > 0 else 0 for t in per_growth ]
print([(x,y) for x,y in zip(per_growth, target)])
```

Answer:

```
[(-75.0, 0), (-33.333333333333336, 0), (150.0, 1), (-100.0, 0), (16.666666666666668, 1), (-9999, 0), (-9999, 0), (700.0, 1)]
```

Edited answer based on comments. Thanks.

Comment: Your `target` values are wrong. They're supposed to be 1 if growth is positive, 0 otherwise.

Comment: The rounding is a nicetouch, but the OP didin't ask for it, so you probably shouldn't add it. To do this using list comps, it's best to use 2 separate list comps. It's more readable, and you don't need to handle the complication that list items might be negative. Eg, `growth = [100 * (y - x) / x if x else -9999 for x, y in zip(a, b)]; target = [int(u > 0) for u in growth]`